# AngularJS/ui-bootstrap radio button group + tooltip?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3sSYCy6y046uDJoqb4X?p=preview

I have a AngularJS/ui-bootstrap radio button group which works, but when I add tooltips to the buttons, they no longer update the model when clicked and don't toggle correctly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying an attribute of the scope is always a bad idea, because if you have a child scope caused by the usage of a directive, the child scope's attribute will be modified, instead of the original attribute in the original scope:

Before click on Second:

```
 parent scope ---> First
                     ^
 child scope --------|
```

After click:

```
 parent scope ---> First

 child scope ----> Second
```

So you should bind the button to an attribute of an object of the scope instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/HlRXqP9r4zAjFWY1PpbY?p=preview:

Before click on Second:

```
 parent scope ---> model1 ---> First
                     ^
 child scope --------|
```

After click:

```
 parent scope ---> model1 ---> Second
                     ^
 child scope --------|
```